# Dask delayed sum gets killed but there are enough resources

Tags: python, dask, dask-delayed, dask-dataframe

I'm creating a function that reads and entire folder, creates a Dask dataframe, then processes the partitions of this dataframe and sums the results, like this:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask import delayed, compute

def partitions_func(folder):
    df = dd.read_csv(f'{folder}/*.csv')
    partial_results = []
    for partition in df.partitions:
        partial = another_function(partition)
        partial_results.append(partial)
    total = delayed(sum)(partial_results)
    return total
```

The function being called in `partitions_func` (`another_function`) is also delayed.

```
@delayed
def another_function(partition):
    # Partition processing
    return result
```

I checked and the variables created during the processing are all small, so they shouldn't cause any issues. The partitions can be quite large but not larger than the available RAM.

When I execute `partitions_func(folder)`, the process gets killed. At first, I thought the problem had to do with having two `delayed`, one on `another_function` and one on `delayed(sum)`.

Removing the `delayed` decorator from `another_function` causes issues because the argument is a Dask dataframe and you can't do operations like `tolist()`. I tried removing `delayed` from `sum`, because I thought it could be a problem with parallelisation and the available resources but the process also gets killed.

However, I know there are 5 partitions. If I remove the statement `total = delayed(sum)(partial_results)` from `partitions_func` and compute the sum "manually" instead, everything works as expected:

```
total = partial_results[0].compute() + partial_results[1].compute() + partial_results[2].compute() \
        + partial_results[3].compute() + partial_results[4].compute()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dask dataframe creates a series of delayed objects, so when you call a delayed function `another_function` that becomes a nested delayed and `dask.compute` will not be able to handle it. One option is to use `.map_partitions()`, the typical example is `df.map_partitions(len).compute()`, which will compute length of each partition. So if you can rewrite `another_function` to accept a pandas dataframe, and remove the delayed decorator, then your code will roughly look like this:

```py
df = dd.read_csv(f'{folder}/*.csv')
total = df.map_partitions(another_function)
```

Now `total` is a delayed object which you can pass to `dask.compute` (or simply run `total = df.map_partitions(another_function).compute()`).

Comment: Hi @SultanOrazbayev, what you say is right. Now the code runs but very slowly. I can split the data and run the code with Pandas in less than an hour (sequentially), but with `dask`, it never finishes (my real data is even larger, so I need `dask`).
I tried a simpler version of `another_function` (random operations on the df's) with `map_partitions`, and it run quickly. However, when I add the real method (a weighted binning where the rows are points), it gets slow. I checked the UI and `top`, and I saw that the workers use little resources, and the processes are sleeping most of the time.

Comment: Are you using any libraries inside `another_function`? If so try importing those libraries within the function (I had similar experience with some libraries).

Comment: Hi, yes, I was using a function from a library which was calling Cython, so I ended up coding the method myself. Not what I'd have wanted, but it works now. Thanks!